# requests.post vs curl -XPOST

Tags: python, rest, curl

i have tried sending post request to https://www.hackthebox.eu/api/invite/generate using both ways. when im using requests.post im getting 404 but when im using CURL it works fine.

requests.post:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.post('https://www.hackthebox.eu/api/invite/generate')
<Response [404]>
```

curl -XPOST:

```
>curl -XPOST https://www.hackthebox.eu/api/invite/generate
{"success":1,"data":{"code":"TEJJS08tWFBBT0EtSUtRV0gtUEVOWUItVFdOU0U=","format":"encoded"},"0":200}
```

what is the difference between both ways and why one is working and the other is not?
thanks.

Comment: use `requests.post(
    "https://www.hackthebox.eu/api/invite/generate",
    headers={
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
    },
)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the service at `www.hackthebox.eu` looks for a `User-Agent` header, which curl sends by default.

Try adding a `User-Agent` in the headers, like:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.post('https://www.hackthebox.eu/api/invite/generate', headers={'User-Agent': 'blah'})
<Response [200]>
```

Answer (score -1):

use the curl -XPOST https://www.hackthebox.eu/api/invite/generate
i could not get it  to work in powershell or command prompt in windows
BUT it did work in terminal on kali linux so try that or any other linux machine or vm